# python iterate over csv with blank lines

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv that looks like this

file.csv

```
"File is","NameofFileA"
"randomdata","1" <-- size of file
"randomdata","32"
"randomdata","43"
 <---->[this is a blank line found in the file]
"File is","NameofFileB"
"randomdata","4" 
"randomdata","3"
"randomdata","1"
```

So what I want to do is end up with a list like this

```
NameofFileA Total = 73
NameofFileB Total = 8
...
..
.
```

I worked out how to get a total from column 2 (row[1])the last column but it doesnt sort it by NameofFileX:

```
with open(csvInput,"r") as inputFile, open(csvOutput ,"w") as outputFile:
    data = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    total = 0
    headerline = inputFile.next()
    for row in data:
        print ', '.join(row)
        total += int(row[1])
    print total
```

Question:
How do I say in a pythonic way say "add up all the items for NameofFileA" ?

The file name always proceeds the cell with "File is" and that "header" row always comes after a blank line like the above.

Im not sure how to work out a blank line then tell it to store row[1] of blank as a file name... then skip line and total everything in row[1] but stop at blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the numbers for a file you could leverage on [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to return you rows from CSV until a blank line has been found. Then just sum the numbers and read the next file from CSV:

```
import csv
from itertools import takewhile

res = []
with open('file.csv') as in_f:
    reader = csv.reader(in_f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # Read next name from CSV
    for _, name in reader:
        # Read rows and return numbers until blank line is found
        total = sum(int(row[1]) for row in takewhile(bool, reader))
        res.append((name, total))

print res
```

Output:

```
[('NameofFileA', 76), ('NameofFileB', 8)]
```

In above [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bool) is used as a predicate to let `takewhile` know if row should be returned. Since CSV reader will return empty row as `[]` and empty `list` is `False` in boolean context `takewhile` will stop there.

Then for each row returned by `takewhile` generator expression takes value from second column and converts it to `int`. Finally these numbers are summed to get the total.

Comment: this is great. Can you explain how this works `for _, name in reader:` what does the _, do?

Comment: @chowpay `_` is just a variable name like `random_data` would be. It's typical in Python to name throwaway variables as `_` to indicate that variable won't be used.

Comment: Just so I understand right, the _,  means ignore "File is" , use "NameofFileA" .

Comment: @chowpay Basically yes, row returned by `reader` is a list `['File is', 'NameofFileA']` which is unpacked by assigning it to two variables: `_, name = row`. After the assignment `_` has value of `File is` and `name` has value `NameofFileA`. There's nothing special with `_`, it behaves like any other variable but it's just named such to indicate the readers that it's not used for anything. It's only purpose is to allow extracting of `name` on the same line as `for` loop since we need two variables to unpack the two values from row returned by `reader`.